# Edit part of a post

Tags: plugins, posts, editor

In some wikis (e.g., mediawiki), if you want to edit part of a page, you can either click an edit link that lets you edit the entire page -- or, if you just want to edit a single section of the page, you can edit just that one section.  This is beneficial because it helps avoid conflicting edits by multiple different editors.

Does Wordpress have any way to support this?  Perhaps via some plugin?

The idea is that I should be able to create a post with multiple sections (separated by headings with style Heading 1, say).  Then there should be a way to edit just a single section at a time, so that Alice can edit section 1 and Bob can edit section 2 at the same time, without risk of a conflict due to their simultaneous operations.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for simultaneous editing](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53203/support-for-simultaneous-editing)

Comment: @ChipBennett, it is not a duplicate; it's a different question.  (That's why I posted two questions.)  The question you reference asks about two users simultaneously editing the *same* content.  This question is about whether it's possible to set up Wordpress in a way that enables the two users to edit *different* content, so their edits don't conflict.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. That does help differentiate the two questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way WordPress is built *now* doesn't really allow for that.

The post content is all in one block in the database - one, continuous database field.  While you might be able to break out sections of it by adding specific markup, you'll still end up parsing the entire content to extract just that section.

To get this kind of functionality, you might want to look at using a custom post type with multiple editors - each with its own header.